Determining if a circuit is complete while protecting microcontroller
I asked a similar question a few weeks ago, but I was new to Stack Exchange and the way I asked it was confusing. I don't want to delete the old one, though, because people tried their best to answer my badly stated question. I hope this is OK. (Switching a low current/low voltage line with a high current/high voltage one. (Detecting current flow)).
I am working on a custom PCB for a model rocket launcher, and I've run into a bit of a problem. One of the most important steps is to check the continuity of the igniter, to see if it is properly attached. The most obvious way to do this is to have a LED in series with the igniter, and a button to test it. If you press the button and the LED lights up, you have continuity! The problem is that if you hold the button, the igniter will light, even on lower voltages.
I would like a way to have the Arduino-based microcontroller already in the design to run the test, so the igniter will only have voltage for an instant. But I can't just connect the negative side of the igniter to an Arduino pin, as I don't know if it can take ~2A at 12V
Here is my current idea, but I have no clue if it will work.

I1 is the igniter. To test the continuity, I set D3 to HIGH, then D4 to HIGH while reading the analog value of A0. If A0 gets a reading of HIGH when D4 is set, then we have continuity! (I know I don't have to use A0 for the reading, but I'm running low on GPIO) To fire the rocket, I can turn D2 to HIGH.

Unless the relay has a flyback diode built in, you need to provide it across the coil.

Thank you, I completely forgot about that

This circuit tries to draw a little under 100μA of current through the igniter:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This "sense" current will flow only if there is an igniter present and connected to its positive supply (+12V). In that case, the transistor detects it and brings the Arduino input low. The input remains high if the igniter, or the igniter's positive supply is absent.
It doesn't need enabling by some Arduino output signal, since the sense current always flows while the igniter is installed, but that current is too small to trigger it.
Use SW1 as usual (your relay or MOSFET, whatever "trigger" system you've chosen), to draw full ignition current. The transistor can only apply 0V or +5V to the Arduino input, regardless of ignition voltage or current.
